# Conditions for a determinant equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A, B, C, D$ be square matrices on a field $K$. I know that if $\det D\neq 0$ and $CD=DC$ then the following holds: $$\begin{vmatrix}A& B\\C& D\end{vmatrix}=|AD-BC|.$$

Question is: Can we remove the $\det D\neq 0$ hypothesis? I have tested it on a large class of $4\times 4$ matrices and I think so, but I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: Maybe we can use something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575952/how-to-proveor-disprove-beginvmatrix-ab-ba-endvmatrix-a2-b2?rq=1)?

Comment: Or $\det A \ne 0$.  See also [THIS](http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at 
$$f(t):=\det\begin{bmatrix}A+t\,I&B\\C&D+t\,I\end{bmatrix}\,,$$
as an element of $K(t)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Clearly, $D+tI$ is invertible over $K(t)$, and commutes with $C$, whence
$$f(t)=\det\big((A+t\,I)(D+t\,I)-BC\big)\,.$$
However, the evaluation $f(0)$ gives the required result.  Therefore,
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}=f(0)=\det(AD-BC)\,.$$

Comment: No need to replace $A$ by $A+tI$. :)

Comment: You are right.  There is no need.  But I will leave it like this because $f(t)$, as it is, is meaningful (as it is more-or-less the characteristic polynomial of the matrix).

Comment: What do you mean when you say that *$D + tI$ is invertible over $K(t)$?* Perhaps I'm missing something obvious

Comment: As an element of the ring $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}\big(K(t)\big)$ (for appropriate $n$), $D+t\,I$ is invertible.  This is because $\det(D+t\,I)$ is nonzero, being a monic polynomial of degree $n$.